# No brokers available error when trying to connect from one docker container to a kafka container on the same network

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to user a docker-compose to spin up a broker, zookeeper and 2 of my own apps.
They all build and run like normal but then when I try to create a kafka producer or consumer from within my app, it throws an exception saying there are no available brokers.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks: 
      - kafka_network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '2181'

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks: 
      - kafka_network
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3

  csir-api:
    build:
      context: app/
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_network

  csir-api-entry:
    build:
      context: app-entry/
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_network

networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: kafka_docker_example_net
```

Here is how I am trying to connect within my app:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    ['clickup-task-created', 'clickup-task-updated', 'sheets-task-updated', 'sheets-task-created'],
     bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

    producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
        value_serializer=lambda x: 
        dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),
    )
```

Here is the error being thrown:

```
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

I expected the producer and consumer to connect on the same network and allow me to consume and produce to the kafka broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `kafka:9092`  is correct from another container.

If you're just running `docker compose up`, then the Kafka container takes a few seconds to properly startup, meanwhile, you python code isn't seeming to wait, therefore will try to connect immediately, and fail.

Since none of your topics exist, I suggest using AdminClient functions in a retry loop to try and create them while waiting for the brokers to become available

Comment: You were right, the broker just hadn't started yet so I just kept retrying every 10 seconds until the connection was successful. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same issue, then i solved it by adding this restart. It restarts my python container till kafka server and zookeeper has started.

```
python_app:
 build: ./python_app
 depends_on:
  - kafka
 restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score -2):

according to your config I would try

```
bootstrap_servers=['kafka:29092']
```

Comment: That would be correct outside of a docker image on the same compose network, but that's not where the code is running, according to the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).